# Dynamic Tabs with Global behaviourSubject?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to hide and show tabs depending on where you are in the Ionic app. I'm currently trying to use a global boolean behaviourSubject to achieve this. I have the following code which has been trimmed for brevity.

In my provider/service globals.ts I have the following:

```
@Injectable() 
export class AppGlobals {
    public showActionTabs:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    setShowActionTabs(val){
        this.showActionTabs.next(val);
    }

    getShowActionTabs(): Observable<boolean>{
        return this.showActionTabs.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then in my tabs.ts I have:

```
export class TabsPage {
    public showTabs: boolean;

    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {
        this._appGlobals.getShowActionTabs().subscribe((value:boolean) => {                    
            this.showTabs = value;
            console.log("new val: ", value, this.showTabs);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log("inside init:", this.showTabs);
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

In my products.ts page I have:

```
export class ProductsPage {

    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._appGlobals.setShowActionTabs(true);
    }
}
```

In my product-details.ts I have:

```
export class ProductDetails {

    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._appGlobals.setShowActionTabs(false);
    }
}
```

Then finally in my tabs.html I have:

```
<ion-tabs class="side-tabs">
    <ion-tab *ngIf="showTabs" (ionSelect)="toggleSearch()" tabTitle="Search" tabIcon="custom-search"></ion-tab>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <ion-tab *ngIf="!tab.hasAction" tabTitle="{{ tab.title }}" tabIcon="{{ tab.icon }}"></ion-tab>
    </ng-container>
    <ion-tab *ngIf="showTabs" (ionSelect)="toggleCompare()" tabTitle="Compare" tabIcon="custom-compare"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

However when I am navigating between the pages, the tabs still do not hide and show accordingly.

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong? My understanding of this method was that the behaviourSubject takes the values from other classes/components and then allows that to be applied somewhere else.

Thanks in advance, it's very appreciated. If you need more detail, please ask.

**EDIT**

My question code has been updated to reflect the answer from @Bhetzie. Currently the tabs still are not showing or hiding although this.showTabs is being set correctly via the behaviourSubject as far as I can tell.

**OUTCOME**

So after some extensive digging I came to the conclusion that the ion-tabs were the culprit to the global behaviourSubject/ngIf seemingly not working together. I ripped them out and made my own tabs using the side menu template provided by Ionic. This fixed my issue and now the tabs swap out dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a getter for the showActionTabs.

It is always going to set showTabs as whatever the behavior subject is initialized as.

You can try:

**service globals.ts**

```
getShowActionTabs(): Observable<boolean>{
        return this.showActionTabs.asObservable();
    }
```

**tabs.ts**

```
this._appGlobals.getShowActionTabs().subscribe((value:boolean) => { this.showTabs = value;
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, this has gotten me a step further. I've applied the tabs code in my constructor. But within the ngOnInit() I set an interval to show the value of this.showTabs every 5 seconds, but it is returning undefined. Shouldn't this be set to the value that is pulled from the tabs code line you wrote?

Comment: What exactly is the idea behind the interval? 

Does it show a value initially? I'm assuming the undefined is because you have: this.showActionTabs.next(val);

So if you're subscribing on an interval there is only the value of false that was set on initialization. 

I think how it's supposed to work is that when a new value is set, ex via products page, showTabs will change to the latest observable value

Comment: I was attempting to see if the value in this.showTabs would change while I navigated between the Products and Product-Details page. But it returns undefined from the very first interval. Sorry I'm probably trying something I shouldn't! Haha. Removing that, it does log the change between true and false navigating the pages. However, the *ngIfs do not change. The tabs do not hide when it's set to false, they still show. :/ Apologies if I'm not making sense, Angular 2 and Ionic I've only picked up over the last week or so!

Comment: In the code that you provided it looks like both conditions are set to showTabs? Should one of them be !showTabs? I'm not familiar with ionic, but if it's possible I might try something like: <ion-tabs class="side-tabs" *ngIf="showTabs"></ion-tabs>
<ion-tabs class="side-tabs" *ngIf="!showTabs"></ion-tabs>

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I forgot to look at stack over the weekend! To be honest the name for the boolean I've used might be slightly misleading. Both those tabs should show and hide together! But as far as I'm aware having it twice shouldn't affect the outcome.